# Relacion entre tabla ventas y tabla persona

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo modelando bases de datos y estoy analizando un modelo de inventario que esta en la web.
En este modelo tienen las tablas Producto, Venta, Persona, entre otros, ahi utilizan la tabla persona para almacenar la información del cliente o proveedor y existe un campo que se llama kind que señala si es cliente o proveedor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema radica en que quiero extrapolar la tabla persona y llamarla ubicación, en donde se pudieran almacenar la información de la Bodega, Cliente, Proveedor,Laboratorio o Proveedor, de forma excluyente al igual que el ejemplo anterior. Mi problema esta en que hay muchos datos que los quiero a nivel de bases de datos como obligatorios, pero si junto todo en una tabla eso no seria posible, Existe otra Solución?

Muchas Gracias!
Gropy

Comment: No termino de entender lo que deseas obtener y que relación tiene esta base de datos con tu problema, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Otro tema. No se puede extrapolar un esquema de una base y suponer que va a servir para otra. Aunque muchas bases sean iguales, cada una tiene sus reglas y no hay una sola forma de armar una base de datos